# Automatically include assets into template

Tags: node.js, dust.js

I'm using the [linkedIn fork of Dust](http://linkedin.github.io/dustjs/) with Node.JS & Express.

My template hierarchy is having:

- 1 layout template - *The base template*
- 1 Page template - *This is the template that will be rendered*
- Optional number of partials - *Might be included by the page template*

**layout.dust** *(layout template)*:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/js/layout.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/layout.css">

        <script src="/js/home.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/home.css">

        <script src="/js/sidebar.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/sidebar.css">

        <script src="/js/widget.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/widget.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        {+content}{/content}
    </body>
</html>
```

**home.dust** *(page template)*:

```
{>layout/}
{<content}
    <div>
        {>sidebar/}
    </div>
    <div>
        {>widget/}
    </div>
{/content}
```

When the user visits the website homepage, then *home.dust* will be rendered, and the user will see a page with the sidebar and some widget. The content of *sidebar.dust* and *widget.dust* is irrelevant.

As you can see in *layout.dust*, there are 4 sets of JavaScript and CSS included in the head section, one for each of the templates and partials. My problem is finding a way to automatically include each asset into the layout (without hardcoding). Ideally I would like to be able to just do this:

```
{#scripts}
    <script src="{.}"></script>
{/scripts}
```

Different pages may require different assets.

- How can I push each script source path into the context of *layout.dust*?
- What do other developers do, do they just hardcode them?

Answer (score 0):

I'd be adding all scripts to the head of the layout without pushing any from the pages that extend from this layout. I'm not sure how knowledgeable you are on javascript minification but it's common practice to bundle all (or most) of your javascript assets into one file and serve them up to the user with a single HTTP request. This speeds up your page a lot; checkout what Google has to say about it [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources).

It's not hard because there are a few tools to do this for you automatically. You could go for an asset manager or [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/).

**ASSET MANAGER:**

There are a few on npm. I found one called [Express Asset Manager](https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-asset-manager) and another called [Asset Pipeline](https://www.npmjs.org/package/asset-pipeline).

**GRUNT:**

Use `contrib-uglify` and `contrib-concat` to handle you minification. There are plenty of others that you should find useful. You can do the exact same thing with all of your CSS too.

Obviously in development you don't really want to try to debug minified code so you can do something like the following:

```
{?production}
    <script src="production-minified-script.js"></script>
{:else}
    {#scripts}
        <script src="{.}"></script>
    {/scripts}
{/production}
```

where `production` is a variable passed to your template from `process.env.NODE_ENV`. To avoid manually adding in each script, you could pass them in as an array by

**STILL WANT TO ADD FROM OTHER PAGES?**

If you still want to add from other pages, add in a block to your head below your main scripts, something like:

```
{+otherScripts}{/otherScripts}
```

Comment: For minification & concatenation, I've built my own custom framework based on uglify-js & clean-css. The framework allows me to dynamically concatenate multiple scripts in a single HTTP message, my real script tags look more like this: `<script src="/js/layout.js;/js/home.js;/js/sidebar.js"></script>`

Comment: I'm not sure how adding a block like `{+otherScripts}{/otherScripts}` can help, I'm still not sure how I'd push the URLs into the context. There are multiple partials included here, and each needs to add their own script to the context.